# Rails how to get count of group by attribute in a child table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Application (:id, :name)

  has_many :steps

Step (:id, application_id, :status)
```

Sample data:

```
  Application       Name
 -------------  ------------
    1              'Peter'
    2              'Paul'
    3              'Mary'

  Step    Application ID    Status
 ------   --------------   -------------
    1           1           'new'
    2           2           'new'
    3           1           'in-review'
    4           2           'in-review'
    5           2           'completed'
    6           3           'new'
    7           3           'in-review'
```

How can I get a report of `count(*)` of *lastest* statuses of applications? i.e.

```
   Status       Count       
 ------------- -------
  'in-review'     2
  'completed'     1
```

Comment: In the example you give, I don't see the relevance of the child table... so to produce the output in your question `Step.select('sum(status), status').group(:status)` will do the job

Comment: @Pierre, the author needs counts of LAST steps.

Comment: Right, my bad. Took me a while to understand, that @ohho wants to grab the latest status of each application and get the count by status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAVING, MAX do not seem to be working with mysql 5.1

This one seems to be working

```
select status, count(status) as "count"
from (
        select status 
        from (
                select * from steps order by created_at desc
             )
        steps_sorted 
        group by application_id
     )
latest_statuses 
group by status;
```

You can use this in Step.find_by_sql